# Internet stop after removing network-manger and installing dnsmasq

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a MacBook Pro. After removing network-manager and installing dnsmasq, I lost internet connectivity. I'm connecting to the internet through the wireless interface (wlan0) and want to setup DHCP & DNS service over the ethernet (eth0) interface.

If I define the wlan0 on the interface file, the interface will not be assigned and IP address from the wireless router, however, if the interface is **NOT** defined, the interface gets a valid IP address but there is no DNS service.

```
# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#If the interface is defined here, I don"t get an IP address from DHCP (why?!)
#auto wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet dhcp

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.10.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

# cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf
domain-needed
listen-address=127.0.0.1
filterwin2k
local=/oeinc.lan/
interface=eth0
bind-interfaces
expand-hosts
domain=oeinc.lan
dhcp-range=192.168.10.50,192.168.2.150

# iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  **ESSID:"Macondo"**  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.765 GHz  Access Point: A0:63:91:D6:88:17   
          Bit Rate=450 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=68/70  Signal level=-42 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:4d:e9:b3:ac:01  
          inet addr:192.168.10.1  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:969596 (969.5 KB)  TX bytes:969596 (969.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:be:08:e9:30:a2  
          inet **addr:192.168.1.5**  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::71a9:2169:3f1:4be8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1394 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:78
          TX packets:212 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:142914 (142.9 KB)  TX bytes:27624 (27.6 KB)
          Interrupt:17 
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
192.168.10.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

# ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.88 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.53 ms

# nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find google.com: REFUSED
```